# JAVACV com maven?

Tags: java, opencv

Efetuei o clone do JAVACV https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

Estou tentando executar o build do projeto:

```
clean install
```

Porém quando executo encontro o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Strings
    at org.sonatype.nexus.maven.staging.deploy.DeployLifecycleParticipant.getPluginByGAFromContainer(DeployLifecycleParticipant.java:238)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.maven.staging.deploy.DeployLifecycleParticipant.getNexusMavenPluginFromContainer(DeployLifecycleParticipant.java:182)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.maven.staging.deploy.DeployLifecycleParticipant.getBuildPluginsNexusMavenPlugin(DeployLifecycleParticipant.java:163)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.maven.staging.deploy.DeployLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(DeployLifecycleParticipant.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Strings
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 18 more
```

Encontrei algumas soluções pesquisando mas até agora nenhuma resolveu:

https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/49

https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:+com.google.common.base.Strings+%2Bjavacv

Tentei adicionar a versão do Guava, porém também não solucionou o problema.

Desde já agradeço !

Answer (score 1):

Veja que para construir o projeto você precisa baixar os arquivos citados no read-me do projeto. Na própria [página](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv#build-instructions) do GitHub do projeto é explicado isso.

Você deverá compilar os projetos em separado. Mas note que isso nem sempre é necessário, você pode baixar os Jars ou usar o Maven para usar o projeto sem compilar.

Para usar no Maven basta adicionar no seu projeto a dependência:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Adicionei as dependências e mesmo assim o erro continua ocorrendo